# Php - find first two characters of input from mysql database using mb_ function

Tags: php, mysql, multibyte, multibyte-functions

Currently, I'm using mb_strrichr function to search characters from database table row but I'm getting one issue. For this input word `helloworld` I want to search it's only first 2 characters from database so that It can search only `he`.

My Current codes are:

```
mb_strrichr($term,$row['letters'])
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

use substr function like this

```
$str = substr($row['letters'], 0, 2);
echo $str;
```

this will give you two characters in $str then do the search :)

Comment: yeah like this. I've tried that already but it's not working.

Comment: could you please see [this link](http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/mb_stristr)

Comment: yeah I need the same thing but through database tables because I've stored all terms and matches in different database tables and getting trouble with that. I'm able to do that by entering term manually like this:

[code]
mb_stristr("helloworld", "llo", false) 
 [/code]

but I don't understand how to do it with database table.